# using R to download files from HTTPS (a SharePoint EDMS) - can it be made faster?

Tags: r, powershell, sharepoint, https, webrequest

Is there a way to improve on this R code to make it faster? Could I use powershell to do so? My csv has three columns (the first is the url the 2nd and 3rd are destination paths).

```
library(RCurl)
library(downloader)

urls<-read.csv("C:/Data/EDMSfetchList.csv", header=FALSE, colClasses = "character")

for (i in 1:dim(urls)[1])
    {
        download(urls[i,1], urls[i,3])
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

On the **PowerShell** side, You can do it.

You can import the CSV in to PowerShell, Then you could use Jobs to start a download for say 5 lines at a time. So instead of doing each row at a time you are processing 5 or 10 rows at a time.

Rough example of how you would achieve this in PowerShell, Has no loading or progress bars:

```
[ScriptBlock]$Script = 
{
    Param($URL,
    $PATH
    )

    $webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
    $credCache = new-object System.Net.CredentialCache
    $creds = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("$Username","$Password")
    $credCache.Add("$url", "Basic", $creds)
    $webclient.Credentials = $credCache

    $webclient.DownloadFile($url, $PATH)
}

$MaxThreads = 10
$SleepTimer = 1000 #Milliseconds
$CSV = import-csv C:\Path\to\csv.csv

foreach($row in $CSV)
{
    While ($(Get-Job -state running).count -ge $MaxThreads)
        {
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $SleepTimer
        }
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $Script -Name $row.url -ArgumentList @($($row.url), $($row.path)) | Out-Null
}

While ($(Get-Job -state running).count -ge 1)
{
    Write-Host "Waiting for last jobs to finish."
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $SleepTimer
}

write-host "Finished processing URLS" -ForegroundColor Green
```

- `$Script` is a block of code that will each job will complete, It expects 2 parameters
- Assumes that the csv has a column header called `url` and header called `path`
- Will start up 10 jobs to download the first 10 rows then as each one completes it will start another. Results in 10 downloads being ran side by side.
- Checks if downloads are completed every 1 second.
- You can tweak the `$MaxThreads and $SleepTimer` to squeeze performance out

Comment: great help. Thx. The files (PDFs) try to copy over but they don't stay (0kb and then removed from the destination folder). I think it's a security certificate issue that is not letting me copy the PDFs via the script. There's no issue if I use my browser to get to the URL and then 'save as'. Any ideas to get around this?

Comment: Does the page require a login?

Comment: yes - i'm using remote access through at VIP. Have not tried your script from work. Don't know how to add security/login credentials all that well.

Comment: I have updated the script block, It will attempt to pass credentials to the sharepoint site using BASIC authentication, You might need to change this to NTLM or something. It should be enough to get you started at least.

Comment: appreciate the help. It's still not working but I'll tinker with it and ask at work.